# Titlesec & titles extending into margin

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, titlesec

I would like to use `titlesec` to have gradient shaded section titles that extend into the left margin.  I would like the section number and the gradient to extend into the left margin, but **would like the section title text to be aligned with the document text**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%              
    {\Large\bfseries
     \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=black!20,right color=white] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%    
    {\thesection}%                   
    {3em}% <---- what do I need here???
    {}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-5em}{*1}{*1}

\begin{document}
\section{Here is my section title}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

It seems as though I would need something like `5em-<sep>-<labelwidth>` but I don't know how to accomplish that.  I would like the result to work regardless of the font or font size used.

Question: How can I, in a font independent way, have the section title text aligned with the text of the document body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost easier to construct the section title with the aid of [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)'s `explicit` option. This allows you to use `#1` as the `<title>` of `\section{<title>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nobottomtitles*,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\hspace{-5em}% Move into margin
   \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=black!20, right color=white] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\dimexpr\textwidth+5em,1em);% Set background shaded rectangle
   \makebox[5em][l]{\thesection}#1}% Set number + title

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*1}

\begin{document}

\section{Here is my section title}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `explicit` and `#1`: it will do the same.